# Laravel error: persistent shutdown of the server

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-9

I'm having a problem with the server; with every change I make on the code I encounter these errors that block the server and consequently repeat the `php artisan serve` command repeatedly to start the server.

Error is as follows:

> ErrorException
>
> ***Undefined array key 58210*** (each time the key number changes)

and the error is on the following line (indicated by the arrow):

```
$request = $this->requestsPool[$matches[1]];
```

> 1 ...\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ServeCommand.php:250
> Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions::Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap{closure}()

> 2 ...\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Collections\Traits\EnumeratesValues.php:264
> Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ServeCommand::Illuminate\Foundation\Console{closure}()

Someone to help me please, I'm going crazy. I tried to find something but couldn't fix this error

Comment: make sure you are running the latest framework release by running `composer update` there seem to have been some changes to serve very recently (like 6 days ago) so maybe this was something that was resolved

Comment: @apokryfos unfortunately it still continues, albeit rarely now